# Stripes's wraps over form inputs don't calculate c:foreach's loop.index value

Tags: java, foreach, web, stripes

I'm doing everything like it is in stripes guide, having simple code in my jsp:

```
<c:forEach items="${management.projects}" var="project" varStatus="loop">
<tr>
<td>
    <c:out value="${loop.index}"/>
    <stripes:text name="project[${loop.index}].projectId"/>
</td>
</tr>
</c:forEach>
```

so then on the html page I can see 0,1,2.. as `<c:out...>` calculated loop.index, but the name of inputs looks like `<input name="project[${loop.index}].projectId" type="text"/>`
instead of `<input name="project[0].projectId" type="text"/>`

I've tried ' and " and differnet combinations of `<c:set..>` and `<c:out...>` but nothing helps.

For html form input I found it looks like 
`<input type="text" name="<c:out value='project[${loop.index}].projectId'/>"/>` and this will look corectly but if I try to use it in a stripes tag like

```
<stripes:text name="<c:out value='project[${loop.index}].projectId'/>"/>
```

it fails again even more so - looks like:

```
<input name="<c:out value='project[${loop.index}].projectId'/>" type="text"/>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It should work, can you try

```
<stripes:text name="project['${loop.index}'].projectId"/>
```

Comment: nope it's just writing additional '' in the html. I'm using stripes 1.5 if it matters

Comment: @AlexeyKuznetsov Strange your code snippet is the same as the stripes example [link](http://www.stripesframework.org/display/stripes/Indexed+Properties) Seems to be a webcontainer problem.

Answer (score 0):

What is your web-container, and what is its version?
For your need EL manipulation must be done by the web container, before passing parameters to Stripes tags.

And I'm not sure whether it is possible to use expressions in **name** attribute of **text** tag.

Jost go for Tomcat 6+